# how do i delete extra zeros in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, string-formatting, currency, tostring

I'm taking DATA like 10.0000000000
but my real data 10,00
how can change this format ?

I'm using this code;
item.sbirimfiyati = String.Format("{?}", item.cbirimfiyati);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this custom code. This is working fine.

```
double yourValue = 10.0000000000;
int x = Convert.ToInt32(yourValue);
string har = String.Format("{0},00", x); // output: 10,00
```